# Missing values in Pandas DataFrame are always empty when written to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For this example, I am using version `1.0.1` of pandas.

I have a DataFrame with mixed types and some missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [1, 2.0, '2020-01-01', 'A String']
    ], columns = ['int', 'float', 'datetime', 'str']
)
df.loc[1] = [pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]
df.datetime = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
print(df)
```

> ```
> int   float   datetime    str
> 0 1   2.0 2020-01-01  A String
> 1 <NA>    NaN NaT NaN
> ```

Let's print the types of the DataFrame to make sure they are what I expect:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

> ```
> int                 object
> float              float64
> datetime    datetime64[ns]
> str                 object
> dtype: object
> ```

Now, I want to write this DataFrame to a CSV file:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Looking at the output CSV, all NaN values are replaced with an empty string. I guess that this is fine for string columns, but it's not exactly optimal for `int`, `float` or `datetime` columns.

How can I get column-specific representations of the missing values?

**EDIT:** It is indeed possible to automatically fill missing values using the `na_rep` argument: `df.to_csv('test.csv', na_rep='NA')`. However, it does not allow column-specific representations.

**SOLUTION:** I guess the best solution so far is to call `fillna` with a dict before writing to CSV:

```
df.fillna(
    {'int': '<NA>', 'float': 'NaN', 'datetime': 'NaT'}
).to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific CSV format that specifies what the values should be. There are a couple of conventions, but ultimately it is down to the program which will use csv afterwards.

Therefore you should use Pandas [fillna](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-fillna-to-replace-null-values-in-dataframe/amp/) function to supply what you want for each data type, before exporting.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False,na_rep='NA')
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this is that it fills the missing values for each column with the same value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fillna() for specific columns to get what value you want.For example

```
df['int column'].fillna(0)
df['string column'].fillna("NA")
```